# Link CentOS server to an NTP Server

Tags: centos, ntp

I have a CentOS 5.5 server that the clock is wrong on. I also have a pre-existing NTP server, but all of the info I can find is focused on setting up an NTP server, as opposed to linking to one. How do I do this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit `/etc/ntp.conf` to contain your NTP servers. I'll use ntp pool servers as an example.

```
server 0.uk.pool.ntp.org
server 1.uk.pool.ntp.org
server 2.uk.pool.ntp.org
server 3.uk.pool.ntp.org
```

Edit `/etc/ntp/step-tickers`. Note there is no word "server" unlike the above.

```
0.uk.pool.ntp.org
```

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/ntpd` -- do you want hardware sync and so on?

Start ntpd and fix any problems if it does not start cleanly: `service ntpd start`

Configure to start on boot: `chkconfig ntpd on`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have sorted the NTP out. Now to go searching for a way to change the timezone, as it looks like it's on standard GMT, not taking account of DST in the UK. Thanks.

Comment: You might also want to tack an `iburst` onto the end of that first server line in `ntp.conf`. This gets the clock set more accurately quicker. Also the clock defaults to UTC (GMT without DST); this is great for a variety of things, especially coordinating log files or events across servers, even in different time zones. Plus, you get used to it pretty quick.